# Reset isDirty-flag

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have this two models:

```
// Subject
export default DS.Model.extend({
    willBeActive: DS.attr('boolean')
})

// StudyPlan
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    subjects: DS.hasMany('subjects'),
    havaChanges: function(){
        var isDirty = this.get('isDirty'), 
         subjectsDirty = this.get('subjects').isAny('isDirty', true);
        return subjectsDirty || isDirty;
    }.property('isDirty', 'subjects.@each.isDirty')
})
```

I use the `EmbeddedRecordsMixin` and the `ActiveModelAdapter` to embed inside the studyPlan payload all the `subjects` that have changed, but when the promise is resolved the `isDirty`flag of each subject remains in `true`. What can I do to reset the `isDirty` flag of each `subject` after saving a `StudyPlan`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interested in [this package](https://github.com/lolmaus/ember-cli-stained-by-children)

It marks a parent as dirty when a child record is dirty and it clears the isDirty field on child records when the parent is saved.